# code': 100, 'error_subcode': 3 in Graph api

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api, http-status-code-100

I used the graph api to upload reel in facebook. At first it worked fine but now i got the error 'code': 100, 'error_subcode': 33

This is my python function

```
def post_video(video_url='',caption='',instagram_account_id='',access_token='',graph_url=''):
    url = graph_url + instagram_account_id + '/media'
    param = dict()
    param['access_token'] = access_token
    param['caption'] = caption
    param['video_url'] = video_url
    param['media_type'] = 'VIDEO'
    param['thumb_offset'] = '10'
    response = requests.post(url, params=param)
    response = response.json()
    return response

post_video('D:/example/reels01.mp4','captin', insta_id, accesstoken, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0')
```

I am exepting the container id
{id:'12345'}

But i got
{'message': "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'v17.017841463282549832' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22), 'type': 'GraphMethodException', 'code': 100, 'error_subcode': 33, 'fbtrace_id': 'AIx0D0zk1ywHPnA901KGxV8'}